# How to set AWS API Gateway Description on serverless.ts?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm using Serverless Framework with aws-nodejs-typescript template ([repo](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/tree/master/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-nodejs-typescript)). On the serverless.ts file, I can set the custom AWS API Gateway name (apiName), but how to set the AWS API Gateway description?

```
provider: {
  name: 'aws',
  runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
  region: 'us-west-2',
  apiName: 'serverless-typescript-hello', // This is AWS API Gateway Name
  /* How to set the AWS API Gateway Description? */
  apiGateway: {
    minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
    shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    description: 'This is for the API Gateway STAGE deployment',
  },
  environment: {
    AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
  },
  lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221',
}
```

**Missing Description**
[Click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osxBl.png)

**Not This Description**
[Click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AguOj.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way (just manually from aws console), you may check it in AWS interface that should be in this package --> @serverless/typescript.

There is no 'description' key inside 'provider'.